# How to use Devise omniauth feature without using additional gem for provider?

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, devise, rubygems, omniauth

I developed myself to get access token and user information from Azure without using any additional gems for providers (all existing gems for Azure are not good, I have to say). All I'm using is the Oauth2 gem.

Right now I have trouble authenticating users return from Azure to get into my application w/o login. Seems Devise and Devise-token-auth gem can only perform it for using additional gems (see this list: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies) Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The provider gems all provide strategies which is how Omniauth integrates with various providers. If you want to write a strategy of your own I would recommend you read the docs for the provider carefully and then look at existing strategies for providers like facebook or twitter which are well maintained. It might be a lot less work to just fork one the existing strategies for Azure and fix its defects. https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/building-a-custom-oauth-strategy-for-doorkeeper/

Comment: You are right, max. I need to write my own local gems and strategies.